# ETL - Pervasive to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, etl, pervasive

I am a SQL Server developer and I have been asked to write some stored procedures to be used to connect a database (Pervasive) to the website.

I was completely unfamiliar with Pervasive before this was asked of me, so I though the best thing to do was to create a SQL Server database (probably express) and have some ETL running nightly moving the data from Pervasive to Microsoft, then I can write all the website code on the SQL Server rather than the live Pervasive database.

Is anyone aware of any free/cheap methods/software for the daily ETL I am planning?

Would SSIS be an option with SQL Server Express?

Comment: No, SSIS requires a minimum of SQL Server Standard

Comment: Why not write the website to connect directly to the Pervasive database?

Answer (score 0):

Lets go the opposite way..

If you are gonna use SQL Server express for your website i would propose something else:

Use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) / [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) for the website.

If you do this, then you can use SSIS to make your ETL from Pervasive -> [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) / [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/).

If and only IF your ETL logic is simple and you just want to get rid of Pervasive, then instead of SSIS you can write your own .NET application to handle the data transfer. In that case you can use SQL Express if you want.